# Python re different results

Tags: python, regex

i'm using regex101.com to test for a string in regex.

The code i use on the site is this:

```
Regular expression = nv[_](.*)[_]

Test string http://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_mv_250_6
```

In my python when i use the suggested code instead of having mv_250 i have nv_mv_250_

The code suggested by the site is this

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'nv[_](.*)[_]')
test_str = u"http://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_mv_250_6"

re.search(p, test_str)
```

Why the result is different?

Comment: The value is in `.group(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you need is a submatch, the contents of the first capturing group. Access it via `.group(1)`:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'nv[_](.*)[_]')
test_str = u"http://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_mv_250_6"
m = re.search(p, test_str)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Jw15yn)

Also, it is a good idea to first check if the match is found before accessing this submatch.

Alternatively, you can use `re.findall` that will return a list of result(s) since it only returns submatches (=captured substrings).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `non-capturing group` with `findall()`.

```
import re
p = re.compile('(?:nv_)(.*)(?:_)')
test_str = u"http://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_mv_250_6"

for item in re.findall(p, test_str):
    print item
```